# Pull NSStrings from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary that looks like this:

```
<PFUser:ObjectID38383:(null)> {
    StartDate = "Jan 09, 2015";
    additional = "FirstName LastName";
    email = "email@yahoo.com";
    fastStats = 1;
    fbId = facebookID;
    prayStats = 12;
    studyStats = 13;
    username = USERNAME;
}
```

I want to pull out various pieces from it to populate a UITableView, mainly 'additional' and 'fbId'.  How would I go about doing this properly?  I have:

```
for(NSDictionary *jobsInfo in jobs) {
                NSLog(@"%@", jobsInfo);

                FriendArray *jobby = [[FriendArray alloc] init];
                jobby.name = jobsInfo[@"additional"];
                jobby.facebookid = jobsInfo[@"fbId"];


                [self.jobsTemp addObject:jobby];

            }
```

But this returns null values.

Comment: It's hard to see how your two pieces of code connect since you are using custom classes, but have you  tried NSLogging the jobs array before the loop? Also you might try `for (id jobsInfo in jobs)` then `NSLog(@"jobsinfo: %@",jobsInfo)`

Comment: @SnoApps That is what I have listed at the top of my question.  That is the NSDictionary.

Comment: That's what it's suppose to be. But since you are getting null you might check first that the array 'jobs' isn't null (Which it probably isn't if you are making it into the loop) then check what is actually inside each element in the array (using id instead of nsdictionary) to make sure you're getting the desired result. If it's still coming out null, Then the problem isn't in the code you provided, but in whatever code you used to make the array of NSDictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you initialise self.jobsTemp array?

you can write.

```
if(!self.jobsTemp){
    self.jobsTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

for(NSDictionary *jobsInfo in jobs) {
    NSLog(@"%@", jobsInfo);
    FriendArray *jobby = [[FriendArray alloc] init];
    jobby.name = jobsInfo[@"additional"];
    jobby.facebookid = jobsInfo[@"fbId"];
    [self.jobsTemp addObject:jobby];
}
```

One more thing there is no need to create property for that jobsTemp array. You can do this using simple object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not initialized your array you can do it with the initializer

```
NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
```

You can retrieve all the objects of dictionary using allValues property

You should use the `NSDictionary` Method `valueForKey:key`

If key does not start with “@”, invokes `objectForKey`:. If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes `[super valueForKey:]` with the rest of the key.

[Here is the reference for Apple Developer Library Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey:)